# Comprimir File Android Studio

Tags: java, android, bitmap, compressão-de-imagem

Estou tentando comprimir meu File que no caso é uma imagem mas ela continua indo com tamanhos acima de 4MB alguém saberia me ajudar. Segue codigo abaixo:

```
   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO || requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_PHOTO) {
            if (data != null) {
                // Get the Image from data
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                assert cursor != null;
                cursor.moveToFirst();


                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                mediaPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

                // REDUZIR O TAMANHO DO ARQUIVO

                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaPath);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);


                if(imageView == null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaPath));
                }
                else if(imageView != null){
                    imageView2.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaPath));
                } else if(imageView2 != null) {
                    imageView3.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaPath));
                }
                cursor.close();

                postPath = mediaPath;
            }


        }else if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST){
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 21) {

                Glide.with(this).load(mImageFileLocation).into(imageView);
                postPath = mImageFileLocation;

            }else{
                Glide.with(this).load(fileUri).into(imageView);
                postPath = fileUri.getPath();
            }
        }
    }
    else if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ocorreu um erro!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Provável que seja algo bobo mas não estou conseguindo resolver, quem souber porfavor me ajude.

Comment: Imagens do tipo JPG, PNG já estão comprimidas. Esses algoritmos de compressão funcionam bem para textos, ou imagens completamente sem compressão (.bmp, por exemplo - sem compressão, uma imagem pode chegar facilmente à 200MB).

Comment: Se achas que 4MB é grande demais, tens que [diminuir (escalar) a imagem](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap)

Comment: Teria como me dar uma luz e mostrar como ficaria o codigo ?

Comment: Preciso que ela seja em KB para fazer uploads

Comment: O link que mandei acima tem exemplos de código que diminuirão o peso da aplicação em tempo de execução. Se não te serve a abordagem ali presente, tu provavelmente terás que diminuir manualmente a resolução (com photoshop, irfanview, etc).